# symlink and unsymlink with existing files

Tags: linux, symlink

Sorry if it seems to be too a simple question or if I have to move my post to another forum (plz tell me if so). 
I have a problem running mysql, I keep on having an error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'(call it files1)
```

but the right place to find socket is `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`(call it files2)

So I have to files `files1` and `files2` and I want to symlink the first by the second like so `ln -s files1 files2`. Now suppose I want to unsymlink, do I delete `files2`, if I run `rm files2` to unsymlink ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the symlink will remove it.  The "target" of the symlink will not be deleted

so if you say

```
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This means that the socket is "found" at `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` as well as `/tmp/mysql.sock`

if you then do

```
rm /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

`/tmp/mysql.sock` still exists but the link at `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` is gone